# In what order should I watch the Death Note movies?

Tags: death-note

I recently watched the *Death Note* anime and I found there are two movies. Is there an order I should watch them in?

Comment: Sorry but I'm talking about anime movies Death Note: Relight: Visions of a God and Death Note: Relight 2: L's Successors

Comment: I generally don't count the anime movies as "movies" because of how much they try to cover in a couple of hours so when I see Death Note Movie I think the live action ones

Comment: So what are they then

Comment: I think one of the wikia pages calls one of them an OVA but not seeing them as movies is just my oppion. some people may like seeing ~614 minutes compressed down to ~240 minutes.

Comment: So are they remake of death note or whole new plot or something like

Comment: They are retelling of the original stories through the shinigami's perspective

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually 3 movies, and all 3 were released in chronological order.

#### [Death Note](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6383)

This is the first movie in which Light finds the Death Note. However, it ends before Light and Misa meet, and deviates slightly from the manga.

#### [Death Note: The Last Name](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6911)

This is when Misa and Light end up meeting and...

> L finds out Light is Kira by writing his own name in the Death Note, making him immune to Rem killing him. Thus, his death scene in front of Light was an act.

#### [L: Change The World](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=8161)

This one is a spin-off set just before the end of the second movie...

> where we see L die in the last scene. The movie takes place during the time L had left before his life was to end because of him writing his name in the Death Note. This movie is also where we first see the live adaptation of Near when L takes a boy he meets to Wammy's House and names him Near.

---

As for the Anime Movies [Death Note Relight: Visions of a God](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_Relight_1%3A_Visions_of_a_God) and [Death Note Relight 2: L's Successors](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_Relight_2:_L%27s_Successors), these are in chronological order as

> the second movie is when Near and Mello appear; they only appear when L dies.

However, while they are feature-length, these are more of an abridged version of the anime, much like the first 2 *Puella Magi Madoka Magica* movies (though the difference is that while the 2 Madoka movies cover 12 x ~25 minute episodes, the 2 Death Note anime movies covers 37 x ~25 minute episodes).

But unlike the live-action movies, the anime movies can be considered a continuation from the anime as Ryuk is actually telling another Shinigami about his experience in the Human World when he was with Light,

> and there is a fan theory that says that the Shinigami is Light. However, the rules of the Death Note invalidate this theory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is,

First would be: [Death Note (film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note_%28film%29) which was latter the same year (2006) followed up by a second movie: [Death Note 2: The Last Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note_2:_The_Last_Name)

The second movie continues on where the first one left off. Which is

> When Misa receives a second Death Note from Rem, another Shinigami. As Light joins the task force after Shiori's funeral, Misa becomes the second Kira and forces a TV station into broadcasting her tapes.